# Register a copied application to registry

Tags: vba, vbscript, mainframe, createobject

I currently have an Mainframe terminal emulator (HostExplorer). My team only have the folder where the executables and dll resides and open the .exe file to run the emulator. 
But I have this idea of automating some things through VB script or something.
The problem is when I am using CreateObject("HostExplorer"), it does not work because the application is not registered in the registry. Is there anyway for me to have "CreateObject" work on HostExplorer.

I am not sure if the file "intall.ini" can help but i will include it below (deleted some codes at the end because of limit of characters per post):

```
[Setup]
DoSiteReg=1
bSysDlltoSysDir=0
VID=0
Name=HostExplorer V6.1.1 for Windows 95/98
Label=HostExplorer
SconfigIns=padrao.ins
InstallIni=install.ini
UserIni=user.ini
SelectAllTrans=0
Ask2DelMisShared=0
LWinSys=2
UserIns=0
MFX=%Xtmp
NoCrossPlatform=1
DiskMargin=115
Product=HostExplorer
Log=1
SysDllSize=9825
LanguageCaption=1

[Registration]
Admin=registration@hcl.com
User=userregistration@hcl.com
Eval=evalregistration@hcl.com

[Critical]
MSVCRT20.DLL=1

[UserCodes]
HostExplorer.User=HostExplorer User Files
HEFTP.User=HEFTP User Files
Rtools.User=Rtools user files
SetupF.User=Setup user files
JConfig40.User=JConfig user files
Wyse.User=Wyse user files
Lpad.User=Launch Pad user files
Inetd.User=Inetd user files
Maestro.User=Maestro user files

[Complete.Precious]
HostExplorer.User.Scheme=0xD5
Lpad.User.Src=0x03
Maestro.User.Src=0x41
Wyse.User.Src=0xF1
Wyse.User.SharedUser=0xFA

[Update.Precious]
HostExplorer.User.Scheme=0xD5
Maestro.User.Src=0x41
JConfig40.User.Src=0x1C
Lpad.User.Src=0x03
Wyse.User.Src=0xF1
Wyse.User.SharedUser=0xFA

[PgmGroups]
HostEx=HostExplorer
Utils=HostExplorer\Accessories|Hummingbird Accessories
Admin=HostExplorer\System Administration|Hummingbird System Administration
Doc=HostExplorer\Documentation|Hummingbird Documentation
Startup=Startup

[PgmShow]
HostEx=1

[PgmLinks]
HostEx=%hhclicons.dll, 102

[Finger]
Home=0x4A

[HostEdit]
Home=0xEB

[Inetd]
Admin=0xA4

[Inetd.User]
Home=0x5C
System=0xC2

[Lpqw]
Home=0xCA

[LPR]
Home=0xED

[Nettime]
Home=0xCE

[Nslookup]
Home=0xCF

[Ping]
Home=0xC0

[Rtools]
Home=0xC6

[Rtools.User]
Hummbird=0xC7

[Tar]
Home=0xE6

[Tar.SelfReg]
%huucomp.dll=1
%hzcomp.dll=1
%hgzcomp.dll=1

[Troute]
Home=0xC1

[Whois]
Home=0x5F

[Logo]
Time=1

[UserInsNoncpx]
SetupFiles=Files for Setup
WinSys.1=System files needed for user install
UserInsCommon=These files are needed for both the server and USERINS

[Directories]
HomeDir=c:\
UserDir=user

[sconfig]
transports=0

[Ctl3d]
ctl3d32.dl_=ctl3d32.dll

[nls]
hclnls.dl_=hclnls.dll

[Ebasic.Ext]
ebs=hclebasics
ebh=hclebasich

[Ebasic.Open]
hclebasics=%hebasic.exe (Ebasic Files)
hclebasich=%hebasic.exe (Ebasic Files)

[Ftp.Ext]
fs=hclftp

[Ftp.Open]
hclftp=%hftp.exe (Ftp Files)

[IconsUSFN]
Socks Help=1

[HEFTP.Tuner]
exename=hntune.exe
sconfigsection=HnTune

[HEFTP.User]
UserINI=0xEE

[SconfigReq]
hostex=0

[HEFTP]
Home=0xFD
HNShared=0xBF

[Ftp]
Home=0x1B

[HostExplorer.SelfReg]
%Hhncomui.dll=1
%Hhncomlib.dll=1
%Hftpseui.dll=1

[HostExplorer.User]
Keymap=0xD2
Scheme=0xD5

[HostExplorer]
Info=0xBD
Home=0xF4
HNShared=0xBF
NLS=0xF5
Samples=0xF7
Devkits=0xF8

[Wyse]
Home=0x19

[Wyse.User]
Src=0xF1
SharedUser=0xFa

[Wyse.SelfReg]
%htermreg.dll=1

[Rtools.SelfReg]
%Xrshctrl.ocx=1

[HEFTP.SelfReg]
%Hhclftpoa.dll=1
%Hhncomui.dll=1
%Hhncomlib.dll=1
%Hftpseui.dll=1

[Ftp.SelfReg]
/E %hftp.exe=1

[Lpad]
Home=0x18

[Lpad.User]
Src=0x03

[Ebasic]
Home=0x11
Eb=0x06

[SconfigC]
Home=0x1E

[mfc40]
msvcrt.dl_=msvcrt.dll
msvcirt.dl_=msvcirt.dll
msvcrt20.dl_=msvcrt20.dll
msvcrt40.dl_=msvcrt40.dll
mfc42.dl_=mfc42.dll
mfc40.dl_=mfc40.dll
olepro32.dl_=olepro32.dll
oleaut32.dl_=oleaut32.dll

[Version]
platform=win95
setup=6.1.1
HostExplorer=6.11
base=6.1.0

[INFO]
INFO=0x02

[Always]
INFO=1
SetupF=1
Maestro=1

[SetupF.User]
Src=0xD7

[SetupF.RegEx]
LM1=Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce

[SetupF.LM1]
Hrunonce=%Xhrunonce.exe(SZ)

[LM]
Description=Hummingbird HostExplorer for Windows 95/98
SoftwareType=Application
Title=HostExplorer for Windows 95/98

[RegDB]
RegPath=Software\Hummingbird\Maestro\NFSClient
DefPath=.DEFAULT\Software\Hummingbird\Maestro\NFSClient
LM=LocalMachine
CV=CurrentVersion
CU=CurrentUser

[PrintExplorer]
Home=0xF3
NLS=0xF6

[Documentation]
Home=0x08

[JConfig40.RegEx]
LM1=Software\Hummingbird\RunOnce

[JConfig40.LM1]
5="%Hhwjview.exe" /cp:p "^H;^Hhcljrccl.jar" RegisterJD(SZ)
6=,-1,""%Sjavareg.exe" /register /class:JconfigdActiveX /clsid:{01021182-0ABE-11d2-9DDD-006008AC6B0B}"(SZ)

[JConfig40.User]
User=0x1C
Sys=0xD8
Java=0xD9
Trustlib=0xDB

[JConfig40.Requires]
R1=MSJavaVM

[JConfig40]
JVMSupport=0xD6
SharedJAR=0x01
Home=0x07
Home40=0xDA

[JConfigAdmin.Requires]
R1=MSJavaVM

[JConfigAdmin]
JVMSupport=0xD6
SharedJAR=0x01
Home=0x09
Help=0x05

[Maestro]
Home=0x0

[Maestro.User]
Src=0x41

[Personal]
CoreComponents1=Wyse HostExplorer HEFTP Whois Finger Ping Troute Lpad
CoreComponents2=Rtools JConfig40 Lpqw Nettime Nslookup Reg Tar
CoreComponents3=HostEdit CmdLpr GuiLpr EBasic Inetd SiteInfo Socks PrintExplorer

[Shared]
CoreComponents1=Wyse HostExplorer HEFTP Whois Finger Ping Troute Lpad
CoreComponents2=Rtools JConfig40 Lpqw Nettime Nslookup Reg Tar
CoreComponents3=HostEdit CmdLpr GuiLpr EBasic Inetd SiteInfo Socks PrintExplorer

[CoreComponents]
HostExplorer=HostExplorer - Telnet, TN3270, TN5250
CmdLpr=Command Line LPR
Finger=Finger
Ftp=FTP
HEFTP=FTP for Windows Explorer
GuiLpr=Graphical LPR
HostEdit=Host Editor
EBasic=Hummingbird Basic
Inetd=Inetd
JConfigAdmin=Jconfig (Java Component)
JConfig40=Jconfig Daemon (Java Component)
Lpad=Launch Pad
Lpqw=LPQ
Documentation=Manuals
Nettime=Network Time
Nslookup=NSLookup
Reg=Online Registration
Ping=Ping
PrintExplorer=PrintExplorer
Rtools=Remote Tools
SconfigC=Sconfig
SiteInfo=Site Information
Socks=SOCKS Information
Tar=Tar
Troute=Traceroute
Whois=Whois
Wyse=WyseTerm

[Uninstall]
Key=Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
DisplayName=HostExplorer for Windows 95/98
UninstallString=%hhcremove.exe

[Restart]
Inetd=1
GuiLpr=1
MSJavaVM=1

[MSJavaVM]
MinBuild=2829

[MSJavaVM.RunProcess.1]
bEnable=0
Cmd=%Jmsjava.ex
Args=/r:n
Args.silent=/q:a /r:n
CurDir=%J
bAsync=0

[RunonceNeeds]
Javasys=1

[Maestro.Ext]
ebx=hclebrun

[Maestro.Open]
hclebrun=%hebrun.exe (Ebrun Files)

[Obsolete]
hbapps.dp=08
hbasic.dp=08
nfsma32.dp=08
nfsmgwug.dp=08
nfsmags.dp=08
hostexgs.dp=08
sologs.dp=08
socks.dp=02
hcltb.dll=00
birdby3.bmp=00
hclprman.dll=00
hcltn3.fon=00
hcltn3eb.dll=00
hcltn3ha.dll=00
hcltn3r.nls=00
hcltn5r.nls=00
hcrexec.nls=00
hcrexecp.nls=00
hcrsh.nls=00
hcrshcp.nls=00
logo4.bmp=00
logo8.bmp=00
lpadcvrt.ebx=00
overstnt.hlp=00
rcprexec.exe=00
rcpw.exe=00
rexecw.exe=00
rshw.exe=00
rutil.hlp=00
sh30w32.dll=00
tn3270.hlp=00
tn3270eb.exe=00
tn5250.hlp=00
upcpx.ebx=00
testdlg.ebs=06
testdlg.ebx=06

[UserObsolete]
ascii.txt=03
austria.txt=03
belgian.txt=03
danish.txt=03
ebcdic.txt=03
english.txt=03
finland.txt=03
french.txt=03
german.txt=03
norwegia.txt=03
setup2.exe=03
spanish.txt=03
sweden.txt=03
tn3270.ini=03
tn5250.ini=03

[ObsoleteItems]
Hummingbird Basic User's Guide=HostExplorer\Documentation
HostExplorer Getting Started Guide=HostExplorer\Documentation
Columbus Lite=Hummingbird NFS Maestro
Inetd=Startup
Socks Help=Suite Maestro
Suite Maestro Help=Suite Maestro
Archie=Suite Maestro
Internet Relay Chat=Suite Maestro
Columbus=Suite Maestro
Cookie=Suite Maestro
EMail=Suite Maestro
Finger=Suite Maestro
Gopher=Suite Maestro
Host Editor=Suite Maestro
LPQ=Suite Maestro
Network Time=Suite Maestro
NSLookup=Suite Maestro
Ping=Suite Maestro
Remote Copy=Suite Maestro
Remote Copy (REXEX)=Suite Maestro
Remote Write=Suite Maestro
Remote Write Server=Suite Maestro
TAR=Suite Maestro
TN3270=Suite Maestro
TN5250=Suite Maestro
Traceroute=Suite Maestro
Whois=Suite Maestro
Wiki Page=Suite Maestro
Common Ground MiniViewe=Suite Maestro
FTP=Suite Maestro
Telnet=Suite Maestro
Launch Pad=Suite Maestro
Hummingbird Basic=Suite Maestro
Inetd Admin=Suite Maestro
Sconfig=Suite Maestro
Remote Exec=Suite Maestro

[ObsoleteDirs]
%Henglish=1
%Hcafrench=1
%Hfrench=1
%Hitalian=1
%Hportuges=1
%Hgerman=1
%Hspanish=1

[Background]
Bitmap=
Company=Hummingbird Communications Ltd.
TextColor=FFFFFF
BackColor=x0000A4
ShadowColor=0x000000
BitmapBGColor=0080FF
BitmapFGColor=404040
screen1=Screen01.bmp
screen2=Screen02.bmp
screen3=Screen03.bmp
screen4=Screen04.bmp
screen5=Screen05.bmp
screen6=Screen06.bmp
screen7=Screen07.bmp
screen8=Screen08.bmp
screen9=Screen09.bmp
screen10=Screen10.bmp

[Startup.SetupF.Icons]
PgmGroup=Startup

[Startup.Hrunonce.Icons]
PgmGroup=Startup
hrunonce=%Xhrunonce.exe|105

[HostEx.HostExplorer.Icons]
PgmGroup=HostEx
TN3270=%htn3270.exe
TN5250=%htn5250.exe
Telnet=%htnvt.exe
HostExplorer Tuner=%Hhetune32.exe
HEFTP LINK=HEFTPLinkHack

[Startup.Inetd.Icons]
PgmGroup=Startup
Inetd=%Xinetd32.exe

[Admin.Inetd.Icons]
PgmGroup=Admin
Inetd Admin=%Xadmin.exe
Inetd=%Xinetd32.exe

[Utils.Finger.Icons]
PgmGroup=Utils
Finger=%hfinger.exe

[Utils.HostEdit.Icons]
PgmGroup=Utils
Host Editor=%Hhostedit.exe

[Admin.JConfig40.Icons]
PgmGroup=Admin
Jconfig Daemon=%Hjconfigd.exe //cp:p ^H;^Hhcljrcsv.jar /settings %Userver.pro|94

[Admin.JConfigAdmin.Icons]
PgmGroup=Admin
Jconfig=%Hhwjview.exe //cp:p "^H;^HJconfig.jar" com.hcl.apps.rcfg.Core.Client.MainFrameContainer|93

[HostEx.Lpqw.Icons]
PgmGroup=HostEx
LPQ=%Hlpqw.exe

[HostEx.LPR.Icons]
pgmgroup=HostEx
LPR=%Hlprw.exe

[Utils.Nettime.Icons]
PgmGroup=Utils
Network Time=%Hnettime.exe

[Utils.Nslookup.Icons]
PgmGroup=Utils
NSLookup=%Hnslookup.exe

[Admin.Ping.Icons]
PgmGroup=Admin
Ping=%Hpingw.exe

[Utils.Rtools.Icons]
PgmGroup=Utils
Remote Tools=%Hrtools.exe

[Utils.Tar.Icons]
PgmGroup=Utils
Tar=%htar.exe

[Admin.Troute.Icons]
PgmGroup=Admin
Traceroute=%htroutew.exe

[Utils.Whois.Icons]
PgmGroup=Utils
Whois=%hwhois.exe

[HostEx.HEFTP.Icons]
PgmGroup=HostEx
HEFTP LINK=HEFTPLinkHack

[HostEx.Ftp.Icons]
PgmGroup=HostEx
FTP=%hftp.exe

[HostEx.PrintExplorer.Icons]
PgmGroup=HostEx
PrintExplorer=%Hhostpr32.exe

[HostEx.Wyse.Icons]
PgmGroup=HostEx
WyseTerm=%hhtelnet.exe

[Utils.Lpad.Icons]
PgmGroup=Utils
Launch Pad=%hlpad.exe

[Utils.EBasic.icons]
PgmGroup=Utils
Hummingbird Basic=%Hebasic.exe

[Admin.SconfigC.Icons]
PgmGroup=Admin
Sconfig=%Hsconfig.exe

[Admin.Socks.Icons]
PgmGroup=Admin
SOCKS Information=notepad.exe /"%Isocks.txt"

[HostEx.SiteInfo.Icons]
PgmGroup=HostEx
Site Information=%Hreg.exe /-S|1@%Hreg.exe

[HostEx.Reg.Icons]
PgmGroup=HostEx
Online Registration=%Hreg.exe

[HostEx.Maestro.Icons]
PgmGroup=HostEx
HostExplorer Help=%hovhe32.hlp

[HostEx.GuiLpr.Icons]
PgmGroup=HostEx
LPR=%Hlprw.exe

[Doc.Documentation.Icons]
PgmGroup=Doc
HostExplorer User's Guide="%Hmanuals\heuser32.pdf"
Hummingbird Applications Guide="%Hmanuals\hbapps.pdf"
Hummingbird Basic Language Guide="%Hmanuals\hbasic.pdf"

[GuiLpr]
Home=0xED

[GuiLpr.RegEx]
LM1=System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Monitors\HCL LPR Monitor

[GuiLpr.LM1]
Driver=%Xhcllpr.dll(SZ)
LPR_Path=%H(SZ)

[CmdLpr]
Home=0xFB

[Inetd.RegEx]
LM1=Software\Hummingbird\Inetd\Telnetd
LM2=System\CurrentControlSet\Services\VxD\HCLTEL

[Inetd.LM1]
Welcome=Hummingbird Communications Ltd., Windows 95/98, Telnetd Version 6.1 (%s)\r\n\r\n (SZ0)

[Inetd.LM2]
NetClean=1(BIN)
Start=0(BIN)
StaticVxD=hcltel.vxd(SZ)

[Utils.CmdLpr.Icons]
pgmgroup=Utils

[UserInsCommon]
sfttb32.dll=Supporting dll
eng.lic=License File
fra.lic=License File
deu.lic=License File
ita.lic=License File
esp.lic=License File
prt.lic=License File

[SetupHelp]
0=setupeng.hlp
1=setupfra.hlp
2=setupdeu.hlp
3=setupita.hlp
4=setupesp.hlp
5=setupprt.hlp

[Filelist.1]
0=msvcrt.dl_|msvcrt.dll|1
1=sfttb32.dll
2=hclshell.dl_|hclshell.dll|1
3=cpx.dl_|cpx.dll|1
4=hcldib.dl_|hcldib.dll|1
5=logo1.bmp
6=setupeng.hlp|setup.hlp|0
7=screen01.bm_|screen01.bmp|1
8=screen02.bm_|screen02.bmp|1
9=screen03.bm_|screen03.bmp|1
10=screen04.bm_|screen04.bmp|1
11=screen05.bm_|screen05.bmp|1
12=screen06.bm_|screen06.bmp|1
13=screen07.bm_|screen07.bmp|1
14=screen08.bm_|screen08.bmp|1
15=screen09.bm_|screen09.bmp|1
16=screen10.bm_|screen10.bmp|1
17=set2eng.nls|setupres.dll|0
18=_setup2.ex|setup2.exe|0

[Filelist.2]
0=msvcrt.dl_|msvcrt.dll|1
1=sfttb32.dll
2=hclshell.dl_|hclshell.dll|1
3=cpx.dl_|cpx.dll|1
4=hcldib.dl_|hcldib.dll|1
5=logo1.bmp
6=setupfra.hlp|setup.hlp|0
7=screen01.bm_|screen01.bmp|1
8=screen02.bm_|screen02.bmp|1
9=screen03.bm_|screen03.bmp|1
10=screen04.bm_|screen04.bmp|1
11=screen05.bm_|screen05.bmp|1
12=screen06.bm_|screen06.bmp|1
13=screen07.bm_|screen07.bmp|1
14=screen08.bm_|screen08.bmp|1
15=screen09.bm_|screen09.bmp|1
16=screen10.bm_|screen10.bmp|1
17=set2fra.nls|setupres.dll|0
18=_setup2.ex|setup2.exe|0

[Filelist.3]
0=msvcrt.dl_|msvcrt.dll|1
1=sfttb32.dll
2=hclshell.dl_|hclshell.dll|1
3=cpx.dl_|cpx.dll|1
4=hcldib.dl_|hcldib.dll|1
5=logo1.bmp
6=setupdeu.hlp|setup.hlp|0
7=screen01.bm_|screen01.bmp|1
8=screen02.bm_|screen02.bmp|1
9=screen03.bm_|screen03.bmp|1
10=screen04.bm_|screen04.bmp|1
11=screen05.bm_|screen05.bmp|1
12=screen06.bm_|screen06.bmp|1
13=screen07.bm_|screen07.bmp|1
14=screen08.bm_|screen08.bmp|1
15=screen09.bm_|screen09.bmp|1
16=screen10.bm_|screen10.bmp|1
17=set2deu.nls|setupres.dll|0
18=_setup2.ex|setup2.exe|0

[Filelist.4]
0=msvcrt.dl_|msvcrt.dll|1
1=sfttb32.dll
2=hclshell.dl_|hclshell.dll|1
3=cpx.dl_|cpx.dll|1
4=hcldib.dl_|hcldib.dll|1
5=logo1.bmp
6=setupita.hlp|setup.hlp|0
7=screen01.bm_|screen01.bmp|1
8=screen02.bm_|screen02.bmp|1
9=screen03.bm_|screen03.bmp|1
10=screen04.bm_|screen04.bmp|1
11=screen05.bm_|screen05.bmp|1
12=screen06.bm_|screen06.bmp|1
13=screen07.bm_|screen07.bmp|1
14=screen08.bm_|screen08.bmp|1
15=screen09.bm_|screen09.bmp|1
16=screen10.bm_|screen10.bmp|1
17=set2ita.nls|setupres.dll|0
18=_setup2.ex|setup2.exe|0

[Filelist.5]
0=msvcrt.dl_|msvcrt.dll|1
1=sfttb32.dll
2=hclshell.dl_|hclshell.dll|1
3=cpx.dl_|cpx.dll|1
4=hcldib.dl_|hcldib.dll|1
5=logo1.bmp
6=setupesp.hlp|setup.hlp|0
7=screen01.bm_|screen01.bmp|1
8=screen02.bm_|screen02.bmp|1
9=screen03.bm_|screen03.bmp|1
10=screen04.bm_|screen04.bmp|1
11=screen05.bm_|screen05.bmp|1
12=screen06.bm_|screen06.bmp|1
13=screen07.bm_|screen07.bmp|1
14=screen08.bm_|screen08.bmp|1
15=screen09.bm_|screen09.bmp|1
16=screen10.bm_|screen10.bmp|1
17=set2esp.nls|setupres.dll|0
18=_setup2.ex|setup2.exe|0

[Filelist.6]
0=msvcrt.dl_|msvcrt.dll|1
1=sfttb32.dll
2=hclshell.dl_|hclshell.dll|1
3=cpx.dl_|cpx.dll|1
4=hcldib.dl_|hcldib.dll|1
5=logo1.bmp
6=setupprt.hlp|setup.hlp|0
7=screen01.bm_|screen01.bmp|1
8=screen02.bm_|screen02.bmp|1
9=screen03.bm_|screen03.bmp|1
10=screen04.bm_|screen04.bmp|1
11=screen05.bm_|screen05.bmp|1
12=screen06.bm_|screen06.bmp|1
13=screen07.bm_|screen07.bmp|1
14=screen08.bm_|screen08.bmp|1
15=screen09.bm_|screen09.bmp|1
16=screen10.bm_|screen10.bmp|1
17=set2prt.nls|setupres.dll|0
18=_setup2.ex|setup2.exe|0

[SetupFiles]
msjava.ex=MS Java VM Installer
setup.exe=Setup phase 1
_setup2.ex=Setup phase 2
install.ins=Setup database
sconfig.ins=System Administrator configuration file
set2eng.nls=Setup Resource
set2fra.nls=Setup Resource
set2deu.nls=Setup Resource
set2ita.nls=Setup Resource
set2esp.nls=Setup Resource
set2prt.nls=Setup Resource
seteng.nls=Setup phase 1 Resource
setfra.nls=Setup phase 1 Resource
setdeu.nls=Setup phase 1 Resource
setita.nls=Setup phase 1 Resource
setesp.nls=Setup phase 1 Resource
setprt.nls=Setup phase 1 Resource
cpx.dl_=Cpx Engine
hclshell.dl_=Shell helper dll
hcldib.dl_=Supporting dll
logo1.bmp=Background Bitmap for Setup
setupeng.hlp=Setup help file
setupfra.hlp=Setup help file
setupdeu.hlp=Setup help file
setupita.hlp=Setup help file
setupesp.hlp=Setup help file
setupprt.hlp=Setup help file
Screen01.bm_=14
Screen02.bm_=15
Screen03.bm_=16
Screen04.bm_=17
Screen05.bm_=18
Screen06.bm_=19
Screen07.bm_=20
Screen08.bm_=21
Screen09.bm_=22
Screen10.bm_=23

[WinSys.1]
Ctl3d=3D Control Support
mfc40=MFC 4.0 DLL
nls=National Language Support
LprSys.1=LPR System files

[WinSys.2]
Ctl3d=3D Control Support
mfc40=MFC 4.0 DLL
nls=National Language Support
LprSys.2=LPR System files

[WinSys.3]
Ctl3d=3D Control Support
mfc40=MFC 4.0 DLL
nls=National Language Support
LprSys.3=LPR System files

[WinSys.4]
Ctl3d=3D Control Support
mfc40=MFC 4.0 DLL
nls=National Language Support
LprSys.4=LPR System files

[WinSys.5]
Ctl3d=3D Control Support
mfc40=MFC 4.0 DLL
nls=National Language Support
LprSys.5=LPR System files

[WinSys.6]
Ctl3d=3D Control Support
mfc40=MFC 4.0 DLL
nls=National Language Support
LprSys.6=LPR System files

[HomeSys.1]
HomeDir=Compressed dlls
HEFTPHOME.1=HEFTP Files

[HomeSys.2]
HomeDir=Compressed dlls
HEFTPHOME.2=HEFTP Files

[HomeSys.3]
HomeDir=Compressed dlls
HEFTPHOME.3=HEFTP Files

[HomeSys.4]
HomeDir=Compressed dlls
HEFTPHOME.4=HEFTP Files

[HomeSys.5]
HomeDir=Compressed dlls
HEFTPHOME.5=HEFTP Files

[HomeSys.6]
HomeDir=Compressed dlls
HEFTPHOME.6=HEFTP Files

[HEFTPHOME.1]
hnsyceng.nl_=%Hhnsynch.nls
hncmueng.nl_=%Hhncomui.nls
ftpsueng.nl_=%Hftpseui.nls
heshleng.nl_=%Hheshell.nls
hftpxeng.nl_=%Hhclftpx.nls
hexfreng.nl_=%Hheftpxfr.nls
heshell.dl_=%Hheshell.dll
hnsynch.ex_=%Hhnsynch.exe
heftpxfr.ex_=%Hheftpxfr.exe
hnwait.ex_=%Hhnwait.exe
hclftpOA.dl_=%HhclftpOA.dll
hncomui.dl_=%Hhncomui.dll
hncomlib.dl_=%Hhncomlib.dll
hclftpx.dl_=%Hhclftpx.dll
ftpseui.dl_=%Hftpseui.dll
csh.dl_=%Hcsh.dll

[HEFTPHOME.2]
hnsycfra.nl_=%Hhnsynch.nls
hncmufra.nl_=%Hhncomui.nls
ftpsufra.nl_=%Hftpseui.nls
heshlfra.nl_=%Hheshell.nls
hftpxfra.nl_=%Hhclftpx.nls
hexfrfra.nl_=%Hheftpxfr.nls
heshell.dl_=%Hheshell.dll
hnsynch.ex_=%Hhnsynch.exe
heftpxfr.ex_=%Hheftpxfr.exe
hnwait.ex_=%Hhnwait.exe
hclftpOA.dl_=%HhclftpOA.dll
hncomui.dl_=%Hhncomui.dll
hncomlib.dl_=%Hhncomlib.dll
hclftpx.dl_=%Hhclftpx.dll
ftpseui.dl_=%Hftpseui.dll
csh.dl_=%Hcsh.dll

[HEFTPHOME.3]
hnsycdeu.nl_=%Hhnsynch.nls
hncmudeu.nl_=%Hhncomui.nls
ftpsudeu.nl_=%Hftpseui.nls
heshldeu.nl_=%Hheshell.nls
hftpxdeu.nl_=%Hhclftpx.nls
hexfrdeu.nl_=%Hheftpxfr.nls
heshell.dl_=%Hheshell.dll
hnsynch.ex_=%Hhnsynch.exe
heftpxfr.ex_=%Hheftpxfr.exe
hnwait.ex_=%Hhnwait.exe
hclftpOA.dl_=%HhclftpOA.dll
hncomui.dl_=%Hhncomui.dll
hncomlib.dl_=%Hhncomlib.dll
hclftpx.dl_=%Hhclftpx.dll
ftpseui.dl_=%Hftpseui.dll
csh.dl_=%Hcsh.dll

[HEFTPHOME.4]
hnsycita.nl_=%Hhnsynch.nls
hncmuita.nl_=%Hhncomui.nls
ftpsuita.nl_=%Hftpseui.nls
heshlita.nl_=%Hheshell.nls
hftpxita.nl_=%Hhclftpx.nls
hexfrita.nl_=%Hheftpxfr.nls
heshell.dl_=%Hheshell.dll
hnsynch.ex_=%Hhnsynch.exe
heftpxfr.ex_=%Hheftpxfr.exe
hnwait.ex_=%Hhnwait.exe
hclftpOA.dl_=%HhclftpOA.dll
hncomui.dl_=%Hhncomui.dll
hncomlib.dl_=%Hhncomlib.dll
hclftpx.dl_=%Hhclftpx.dll
ftpseui.dl_=%Hftpseui.dll
csh.dl_=%Hcsh.dll

[HEFTPHOME.5]
hnsycesp.nl_=%Hhnsynch.nls
hncmuesp.nl_=%Hhncomui.nls
ftpsuesp.nl_=%Hftpseui.nls
heshlesp.nl_=%Hheshell.nls
hftpxesp.nl_=%Hhclftpx.nls
hexfresp.nl_=%Hheftpxfr.nls
heshell.dl_=%Hheshell.dll
hnsynch.ex_=%Hhnsynch.exe
heftpxfr.ex_=%Hheftpxfr.exe
hnwait.ex_=%Hhnwait.exe
hclftpOA.dl_=%HhclftpOA.dll
hncomui.dl_=%Hhncomui.dll
hncomlib.dl_=%Hhncomlib.dll
hclftpx.dl_=%Hhclftpx.dll
ftpseui.dl_=%Hftpseui.dll
csh.dl_=%Hcsh.dll

[HEFTPHOME.6]
hnsycprt.nl_=%Hhnsynch.nls
hncmuprt.nl_=%Hhncomui.nls
ftpsuprt.nl_=%Hftpseui.nls
heshlprt.nl_=%Hheshell.nls
hftpxprt.nl_=%Hhclftpx.nls
hexfrprt.nl_=%Hheftpxfr.nls
heshell.dl_=%Hheshell.dll
hnsynch.ex_=%Hhnsynch.exe
heftpxfr.ex_=%Hheftpxfr.exe
hnwait.ex_=%Hhnwait.exe
hclftpOA.dl_=%HhclftpOA.dll
hncomui.dl_=%Hhncomui.dll
hncomlib.dl_=%Hhncomlib.dll
hclftpx.dl_=%Hhclftpx.dll
ftpseui.dl_=%Hftpseui.dll
csh.dl_=%Hcsh.dll

[Homedir]
hclshell.dl_=%Hhclshell.dll
hcldib.dl_=%Hhcldib.dll
cpx.dl_=%Hcpx.dll

[LprSys.1]
hcllpr.dl_=%Xhcllpr.dll
hclpreng.nl_=%Xhcllpr.nls

[LprSys.2]
hcllpr.dl_=%Xhcllpr.dll
hclprfra.nl_=%Xhcllpr.nls

[LprSys.3]
hcllpr.dl_=%Xhcllpr.dll
hclprdeu.nl_=%Xhcllpr.nls

[LprSys.4]
hcllpr.dl_=%Xhcllpr.dll
hclprita.nl_=%Xhcllpr.nls

[LprSys.5]
hcllpr.dl_=%Xhcllpr.dll
hclpresp.nl_=%Xhcllpr.nls

[LprSys.6]
hcllpr.dl_=%Xhcllpr.dll
hclprprt.nl_=%Xhcllpr.nls

[Setup Languages]
0=English; 1; setENG.nls
1=Français; 2; setFRA.nls
2=Deutsch; 3; setDEU.nls
3=Italiano; 4; setITA.nls
4=Español; 5; setESP.nls
5=Português; 6; setPRT.nls

[License]
English=ENG.lic
Français=ENG.lic
Deutsch=ENG.lic
Italiano=ENG.lic
Español=ENG.lic
Português=ENG.lic

[WizBitmap]
Welcome=0
Admin=3
SetupType=9
InstallType=9
Home=4
User=4
Component=2
DefUser=6
Fonts=7
Summary=8

[Moniker]
x00=%H
x01=%H
x02=%Hinfo
x03=%U
x04=%U
x05=%HHTMLhelp
x06=%Heb
x07=%H
x08=%Hmanuals
x09=%H
x0A=%Hfont\misc
x0B=%Hfont\75dpi
x0C=%Hfont\100dpi
x0D=%Hfont\andrew
x0E=%Hfont\pc
x0F=%Hfont\hpfont
x10=%HSpareMoniker
x11=%H
x12=%H
x13=%Hfont\chinese
x14=%H
x15=%Hfont\japanese
x16=%Hfont\korean
x17=%H
x18=%H
x19=%H
x1A=%H
x1B=%H
x1C=%U
x1D=%Hfont\siemens
x1E=%H
x1F=%H
x20=%H
x21=%U
x22=%Hxdk\lib
x23=%U
x24=%Hxdk\include\x11
x25=%Hfont\euro
x26=%H
x27=%HSpareMoniker
x28=%Hxdk\lib
x29=%Hxdk\src\pplane
x2A=%Hxdk\include\GL
x2B=%H
x2C=%U
x2D=%Hxdk\include\x11\GLW
x2E=%Hxdk\src\xglinfo
x2F=%I
x30=%Hxdk\include\x11\bitmaps
x31=%Hxdk\include\x11\xaw
x32=%Hxdk\include\x11\xmu
x33=%Hxdk\include\x11\extensions
x34=%Hxdk\include\x11\extensio
x35=%H
x36=%Huser
x37=%S
x38=%Hxdk\include\x11\bitmaps
x39=%Hxdk\include\xm
x3A=%Hxdk\include\mrm
x3B=%Hxdk\include\uil
x3C=%Hxdk\motif12\include\xm
x3D=%Hxdk\motif12\lib
x3E=%Hxdk\motif12\include\uil
x3F=%Hxdk\motif12\include\mrm
x40=%Huser
x41=%U
x42=%Xtemp
x43=%Xtemp\system
x44=%Hfont\dec75
x45=%Hfont\dec100
x46=%Hxdk\gcc\lib
x47=%Hxdk\motif12\gcc\lib
x48=%HSpareMoniker
x49=%HSpareMoniker
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible but you will need to understand how HostExplorer implements OLE Automation. A quick search has found the following documentation [here](http://mimage.hummingbird.com/alt_content/binary/pdf/support/nc/automatinghostapplications.pdf).

What you may find is that you need HostExplorer to be opened and running prior to trying to use `CreateObject` as often with these Terminal Emulator applications they will only 'attach' to a currently running instance of the application.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Correct me if I'm wrong but I think my problem here is that HostExplorer is not registered in registry that's why i cannot issue a command CreateObject (I tried in VBA macro). I can easily implement the methods of HostExplorer if I get the CreateObject("HostEplorer") working.

Comment: Sorry, yes you're right if HostExplorer hasn't been properly installed and you only have the EXE it may not be registered correctly however ordinarily I believe simply running an application should be sufficient for it to register itself. You can manually invoke it from the command line. To do this you run the application using /RegServer eg. `hostexplorer.exe /RegServer` This should 'register' the application in the registry pointing to where you have the EXE stored.

Comment: Ok. I tried you're solution above but it gave me an error: "There was a problem launching this profile". You are either missing the appropriate helper application or the path specified is invalid".

I had the cmd point in the correct path but still no luck. Also tried running cmd as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Having trouble working with 2 instalations at the same time (HostExplorer 6.2 & Hummingbird HostExplorer 9) the linking of the .dll files for automation was lost.

To call the hostexplorer object from VB6 first run:

```
"C:\Program Files\HostExplorer.nt\HOSTEX32.EXE /Automation"
```

Then call the object like:

```
CreateObject("HostExplorer")
```